# Better way to setup a nested object structure

Tags: python, oop, selenium-webdriver

I've recently started with Python and want to write a simple API for data scrapping from a web side with selenium. Now I am having issues with keeping the code organized.

Currently it looks something like this

```
def get_tasks():
   # Init driver and open requried page
   driver = init()
   class TasksView:
      def get_task_names():
         print("Reads all task names and returns their names using driver.findElements")
      def open_task(name):
         print("Open task, this will change the DOM structure")
         class TaskView:
            def get_details():
               print("Returns details by using driver.findElements")
            def get_creation():
               print("Returns creation date by using driver.findElements")
            def close():
               print("Close task, returning DOM structure to how it was after calling get_tasks")
         return TaskView()
   return TasksView()

task_view = get_tasks()
task = task_view.open_task("buy_cheese")
print(task.get_details())
task.close()
```

How can I make this more readable? It's already very nested and with more complicated data structures it would be a real mess.

Answer (score 0):

In order to clean up you code example and make it more readable, you can move your classes out of each other.

Also, if possible, change the class names, as TaskView and TasksView are prone to misstyping errors.

```
class TaskView:
    def get_details(self):
        return "Returns details by using driver.findElements"

    def get_creation(self):
        print("Returns creation date by using driver.findElements")

    def close(self):
        print("Close task, returning DOM structure to how it was after calling get_tasks")


class TasksView:
    def get_task_names(self):
        print("Reads all task names and returns their names using driver.findElements")

    def open_task(self, name):
        print("Open task, this will change the DOM structure")
        return TaskView()


def get_tasks():
    # Init driver and open requried page
    # driver = init()
    return TasksView()


task_view = get_tasks()
task = task_view.open_task("buy_cheese")
print(task.get_details())
task.close()
```

You could even split up the classes into files if it helps to organize your code.

```
# file: taskview.py
class TaskView:
    def get_details(self):
        return "Returns details by using driver.findElements"

    def get_creation(self):
        print("Returns creation date by using driver.findElements")

    def close(self):
        print("Close task, returning DOM structure to how it was after calling get_tasks")
```

```
# file: tasksview.py
from taskview import TaskView


class TasksView:
    def get_task_names(self):
        print("Reads all task names and returns their names using driver.findElements")

    def open_task(self, name):
        print("Open task, this will change the DOM structure")
        return TaskView()
```

```
#file: main.py
from tasksview import TasksView


def get_tasks():
    # Init driver and open requried page
    # driver = init()
    return TasksView()


task_view = get_tasks()
task = task_view.open_task("buy_cheese")
print(task.get_details())
task.close()
```

Comment: You need to think about the classes as APIs that interact with a website in the background. When `TasksView` is create the `driver` object is on the task list site. When you open a task the `driver` has the state of the task details site. I am basically navigating on a web site with different classes and the classes provide interaction with the current state of the web site. So while your proposal is good it wouldn't work because opening a task implies I am on the task list and opening the task details from there.

Comment: So you are forced to return classes to meet the needs of your environment. You can do this without nesting the classes into each other. You don't even have to put them in the same file. I'll update my answer.